# Appendix with titletoc and memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, appendices, titletoc

I'm trying to customize the TOC layout with `titletoc` in a `memoir` document.

The `chapter` styling works well as below, but if I try the `appendix` section, I'll get an error for missing number.

I think I see that this is because `\chapternumberline` is renewed to `\numberline`, and that doesn't take in the `A` as the appendix number.

But if `\chapternumberline` isn't renewed this way, it errors out with `Undefined control sequence` for `\@chapapp@head` in the `memoir` definition:

```
\newcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{%
  \chapternumberlinehook{#1}%
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\@chapapp@head\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil}%
  \@cftasnumb}
```

So it looks like `memoir` is locking horns with `titlesec`. Any suggestions to on how to pacify them?

The aim is to have the appendix appear similar to the chapter:

```
 Chapter 1 * It Came Into My Head         3
Appendix A * The Time Machine             5
```

(In the MWE below the appendix styling is commented out, otherwise it would be MNWE)

[image]

`mwe.toc`

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {1}It Came Into My Head}{3}
\contentsline {appendix}{\chapternumberline {A}The Time Machine}{5}
\contentsfinish
```

`mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

% Fixes Undefined control sequence error for \@chapapp@head
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\numberline{#1}}

\titlecontents{chapter}[6pc]
{\normalsize}%
{%
  \contentsmargin{0pt}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \chaptername~{\thecontentslabel}%
    \hspace*{0.5em}$\cdot$\hspace*{0.5em}%
  }%
}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}%
\itshape}
{\hfill\normalsize\thecontentspage}

% FIXME: perhaps \numberline is erroring out b/c "A" is not numerical
%! Missing number, treated as zero.
%<to be read again>
%                   \ttll@appendix
%l.21 ...rline {A}The Time Machine}{11}{appendix.A}

%\titlecontents{appendix}[6pc]
%{\normalsize}%
%{%
%  \contentsmargin{0pt}%
%  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
%    \appendixname~{\thecontentslabel}%
%    \hspace*{0.5em}$\cdot$\hspace*{0.5em}%
%  }%
%}
%{\contentsmargin{0pt}%
%\itshape}
%{\hfill\normalsize\thecontentspage}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{It Came Into My Head}

'In another moment we were standing face to face, I and this fragile thing out of futurity\ldots

\appendix

\chapter{The Time Machine}

'There were others coming, and presently a little group of perhaps eight or ten\ldots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `\let` the command `\ttll@appendix` to be `\ttll@chapter`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
%\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

% Fixes Undefined control sequence error for \@chapapp@head
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\numberline{#1}}

\titlecontents{chapter}[6pc]
{\normalsize}%
{%
  \contentsmargin{0pt}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \chaptername~{\thecontentslabel}%
    \hspace*{0.5em}$\cdot$\hspace*{0.5em}%
  }%
}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}%
\itshape}
{\hfill\normalsize\thecontentspage}

\makeatletter
\let\ttll@appendix\ttll@chapter
\titlecontents{appendix}[6pc]
{\normalsize}%
{%
  \contentsmargin{0pt}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \appendixname~{\thecontentslabel}%
    \hspace*{0.5em}$\cdot$\hspace*{0.5em}%
  }%
}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}%
\itshape}
{\hfill\normalsize\thecontentspage}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{It Came Into My Head}

'In another moment we were standing face to face, I and this fragile thing out of futurity\ldots

\appendix
\chapter{The Time Machine}

'There were others coming, and presently a little group of perhaps eight or ten\ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of using `titletoc` (which might produce problems if `hyperref` is going yo be used), you could use the built in mechanisms offered by `memoir` and inspired in the `tocloft` package; a little example producing a result similar to the one you want (some details still have to be adjusted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
%\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cftchapteraftersnum{\hspace{0.5em}$\cdot$\hspace{0.5em}}
\settowidth\mylen{\cftchapterpresnum\cftchapteraftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapternumwidth{\mylen}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\itshape}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@chapapp{\makebox[7em][l]{\hfill\chaptername~}#1}{#2}{\cftchaptername}}
\renewcommand*{\l@appendix}[2]{%
  \l@chapapp{\makebox[7em][l]{\hfill\appendixname~}#1}{#2}{\cftappendixname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{It Came Into My Head}

'In another moment we were standing face to face, I and this fragile thing out of futurity\ldots

\appendix
\chapter{The Time Machine}

'There were others coming, and presently a little group of perhaps eight or ten\ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my example I commented out the line `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}` since I don't have that font.

Comment: Awesome! I thought `TeX Gyre Pagella` was part of every distribution, but I'll stop using it in my examples then.